# Running a consumer and api on port golang

Tags: go, amqp, go-gin

I have a go api project where I also run a worker (RabbitMQ). I just discovered a problem that my worker and my http listen and serve do not work together. The moment I run the worker, the port of api is not reached.

Here is what my code looks like.

> app.go

```
func (a *App) StartWorker() {

    connection, err := amqp091.Dial(os.Getenv("AMQP_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer connection.Close()

    consumer, err := events.NewConsumer(connection, database.GetDatabase(a.Database))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    consumer.Listen(os.Args[1:])

}

func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
    logs := log.New(os.Stdout, "my-service", log.LstdFlags)

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         addr,
        Handler:      a.Router,
        ErrorLog:     logs,
        IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second, // max time for connections using TCP Keep-Alive
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }

    go func() {
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            logs.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    // trap sigterm or interrupt and gracefully shutdown the server
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Kill)

    sig := <-c
    logs.Println("Recieved terminate, graceful shutdown", sig)
    tc, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    server.Shutdown(tc)
}
```

here is my

> consumer.go

```
// NewConsumer returns a new Consumer
func NewConsumer(conn *amqp.Connection, db *mongo.Database) (Consumer, error) {
    consumer := Consumer{
        conn: conn,
        db:   db,
    }
    err := consumer.setup()
    if err != nil {
        return Consumer{}, err
    }

    return consumer, nil
}

// Listen will listen for all new Queue publications
// and print them to the console.
func (consumer *Consumer) Listen(topics []string) error {

    ch, err := consumer.conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer ch.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    msgs, err := ch.Consume("update.package.rating", "", true, false, false, false, nil)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for msg := range msgs {
            switch msg.RoutingKey {
            case "update.package.rating":
                worker.RatePackage(packageRepo.NewPackagesRepository(consumer.db), msg.Body)
            }
            // acknowledege received event
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", msg.Body)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf("[*] Waiting for message [Exchange, Queue][%s, %s]. To exit press CTRL+C", getExchangeName(), "update.package.rating")
    <-forever
    return nil
}
```

> main.go

```
func main() {
    start := app.App{}
    start.StartApp()
    start.StartWorker()
    start.Run(":3006")
}
```

the port 3006 is not reached.

I am using gin-gonic to serve my http request.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: The consumer.Listen never returns. Did you mean to run it in a goroutine?

Comment: Yes, I ended up running my trapsigterm in a goroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem while using gin framework.Solved the issue by running my consumer inside a go routine.I invoked my consumer like below.

```
go notificationCallback.ConsumeBankTransaction()
```

and both the server and the rabbitmq consumer run seamlessly.Still monitoring performance to see if it is robust and resilient enough.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Let me know if you notice a performance drop please.

Comment: Deployed succesafully.No noticeable performance drop.